# Having trouble attaching a file to an API call using Postman

Tags: c#, api, file, postman

I have read many articles and none are exactly what I need (or the solutions don't work for me).  I am calling an API which is already in use and working when called from a .Net ashx.cs page.  The API starts like this, and I can't get past it when calling from postman.

```
[HttpPost]    
[Route("api/file")]    
public HttpResponseMessage SendFile()
{

    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count < 1)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

I have the file listed in postman form data

[image]

The 10 headers are all postman generated, and the auth bearer token works in another call.

Has anyone else encountered and fixed this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, its so easy I almost just deleted my post, but someone else may miss this in the future.  The image being uploaded needs to be in the postman working directory.  That simple, but took me a while to get there.

Comment: That's not true. The file can be located anywhere in the system.

Comment: Funny, the error said 'This file isn't in your working directory' in the console window.  In red.  As soon as I moved it to the postman directory it worked.  Maybe you can change a setting or property to allow them from different locations, but by default they have to be in the postman directory.

Comment: Or may be doesn't have permission to read or modify on that file location.

Comment: I don't think that was it, I have admin permissions and its running on my local machine.  IMO the error is indicating that it can only attach a file in this fashion from the local postman directory.